# Does urg_node work with Hokuyo's new UST-10LX?

Tags: ros, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tested the urg_node to see if it works with Hokuyo's new UST-10LX?
https://www.hokuyo-aut.co.jp/02sensor/07scanner/ust_10lx_20lx.html

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153806/does-urg_node-work-with-hokuyo%27s-new-ust-10lx?/) by [bk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7086/bk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it should. I've run urg_node with a UST-20LX with no problems.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-08-18**:
I'm also trying to use UST-20LX, the interface is Ethernet you know. The urg node can't recognize the device. How do you make it ?